# Haskell type Converting errors

Tags: haskell

a newbie and have made this code in winHugs Haskell to check the maximum exponent k can be induced, that 2 power k is the divisor of n:

```
maxexp2 ::Int -> Int
maxexp2 n 
    | n==0 || 2^k`mod`n /= 0  = 0
    | otherwise == k
  where k = e `div` f    
        e = round (fromIntegral(log n))
        f = round (fromIntegral (log 2))
```

Somehow I know there is something fishy with the e and f part ...the error says : fractional Int instance is needed for the execution of this function. 
I don't really understand that...can someone please explain it to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the logarithm of almost all numbers is something irrational, so using `fromIntegral` on it should indeed seem fishy to you. Why do you even think you need it on that point? Where you do need it is *before* the logarithm, because that actually also *accepts* only values of the `Floating` class, as we can easily find out<sup>1</sup>:

> Prelude> :t log
>   log :: Floating a => a -> a

So it hase to be `e = round (log $ fromIntegral n)`. You don't need it for `f` at all, because `2` is just a generic `Num` literal, not an `Int`. Obviously though, it can't be right to just `round` the `log 2`, because that is simply `1`. What you probably want is `round $ e / f` with floating-point `e` and `f`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I don't know if this works in Hugs; probably. If not, use GHCi (why does everybody new seem to use Hugs at the moment anyway? I don't know why you would use anything else but GHC).